# Concatenating strings in Perl with "join"

Tags: perl

***See Update Below***

I am going through a whole bunch of Perl scripts that someone at my company wrote. He used `join` to concatenate strings. For example, he does this (taken hot out of a real Perl script):

```
$fullpath=join "", $Upload_Loc, "/", "$filename";
```

Instead of this:

```
$fullpath = "$Upload_Loc" . "/" . "$filename";
```

Or even just this:

```
$fullpath = "$Upload_Loc/$filename";
```

He's no longer here, but the people who are here tell me he concatenated strings in this way because it was somehow *better*. (They're not too clear why).

So, why would someone use `join` in this matter over using the `.` concatenate operator, or just typing the strings together as in the third example? Is there a valid reason for this style of coding?

I'm trying to clean up lot of the mess here, and my first thought would be to end this practice. It makes the code harder to read, and I'm sure doing a `join` is not a very efficient way to concatenate strings. However, although I've been writing scripts in Perl since version 3.x, I don't consider myself a guru because I've never had a chance to hang around with people who were better than Perl than I am and could teach me Perl's deep inner secrets. I just want to make sure that my instinct is correct here before I make a fool of myself.

I've got better ways of doing that around here.

---

#### Update

People are getting confused. He isn't just for concatenating paths. Here's another example:

```
$hotfix=join "", "$app", "_", "$mod", "_", "$bld", "_", "$hf", ".zip";
```

Where as I would do something like this:

```
$hotfix = $app . "_"  $mod . "_" . $bld . "_" . "$hf.zip";
```

Or, more likely

```
$hotfix = "${app}_${mod}_${bld}_${hf}.zip";
```

Or maybe in this case, I might actually use `join` because the underscore causes problems:

```
$hotfix = join("_", $app, $mod, $bld, $hf) . ".zip";
```

My question is still: Is he doing something that real Perl hackers know, and a newbie like me who's been doing this for only 15 years don't know about? Do people look at me concatenating strings using `.` or just putting them in quotes and say "Ha! What a noob! I bet he owns a Macintosh too!"

Or, does the previous guy just has a *unique style* of programming much like my son's *unique style* of driving includes running head on into trees?

Comment: The plain-old string expansion (3rd example) looks good to me.  I suspect the people who think the 1st version is somehow better know even less about Perl than you or the dev you're replacing =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done my fair share of commercial Perl development for "a well known online retailer", and I've never seen `join` used like that. Your third example would be my preferred alternative, as it's simple, clean and readable.

Like others here, I don't see any genuine value in using `join` as a performance enhancer. It might well perform marginally better than string interpolation but I can't imagine a real-world situation where the optimisation could be justified yet the code still written in a scripting language.

As this question demonstrates, esoteric programming idioms (in any language) just lead to a lot of misunderstanding. If you're lucky, the misunderstanding is benign. The developers I enjoy working alongside are the ones who code for readability and consistency and leave the Perl Golf for the weekends. :)

In short: yes, I think his unique style is akin to your son's unique style of driving. :)

Comment: I suspected as much. I don't think he really knows Perl. Just things like indents are scattered and poorly done. Variable names don't follow any convention. I think he needed to concat strings, using commas didn't work, and thus he read through a list of Perl functions, and "join" seemed to be what the doctor ordered.

Answer (score 4):

I would consider

```
$fullpath = join "/", $Upload_Loc, $filename;
```

clearer than the alternatives. However, [File::Spec](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File%3a%3aSpec) has been in the core for a long time, so

```
use File::Spec::Functions qw( catfile );
# ...
$fullpath = catfile $Upload_Loc, $filename;
```

is much better. And, better yet, there is [Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Path%3a%3aClass):

```
use Path::Class;

my $fullpath = file($Upload_Loc, $filename);
```

Speed is usually not a factor I consider in concatenating file names and paths.

The example you give in your update:

```
$hotfix=join "", "$app", "_", "$mod", "_", "$bld", "_", "$hf", ".zip";
```

demonstrates why the guy is clueless. First, there is no need to interpolate those individual variables. Second, that is better written as

```
$hotfix = join '_', $app, $mod, $bld, "$hf.zip";
```

or, alternatively, as

```
$hotfix = sprintf '%s_%s_%s_%s.zip', $app, $mod, $bld, $hf;
```

with *reducing unnecessary punctuation* being my ultimate goal.

Comment: If I was creating directory and file names in a machine independent manner, I would use File::Spec, but that wasn't my question. My question is why did he concatenate strings that way when he simply could have done it in the other two ways. This was just one sample. In another, he did this: join "", "$app", "_", "$mod", "_", $bld, "_", "$hf"; In other words, this is the way he concatenates strings.

Comment: @David: `join ""` is pointless in this case. However, I would consider `join '_', @list` to be find. Ultimately, it is not platform independence I care about. It is readability. And, in that regard `File::Spec::catfile` and `Path::Class::file` carry the day. I do not consider `"$this/$that/$and/$theother"` or `$this . "/" . $that . "/" . $and . "/" . $theother` to be readable.

Comment: "$this/$that/$and/$theother" not readable? To me, it's the most readable form because I don't have to mentally map out the string. Using "join" or "sprintf" means I have to mentally map out the string because the elements in the command aren't in the order they'll be in the string. Yes, it's not exactly a Mensa test question, but it still takes a few brief milliseconds to think of the answer. The gotcha is when you have underscores which confuses the Perl interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

In general, unless the lists of items to be joined are huge, you will not see much of a performance difference changing them over to concatenations.  The main concern is readability and maintainability, and in those cases, if the string interpolation form is clearer, you can certainly use that.

I would guess that this is just a personal coding preference of the original programmer.

In general, I use `join` when the length of the list is large/unknown, or if I am joining with something other than the empty string (or a single space for array interpolation).  Otherwise, using `.` or simple string interpolation is usually shorter and easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Perl compiles double-quoted strings into things with `join` and `.` catenation in them:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse,-q -e '$fullpath = "$Upload_Loc/$filename"'
$fullpath = $Upload_Loc . '/' . $filename;
-e syntax OK

$ perl -MO=Deparse,-q -le 'print "Got @ARGV"'
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
print 'Got ' . join($", @ARGV);
-e syntax OK
```

which may inspire you to things like this:

```
$rx = do { local $" = "|"; qr{^(?:@args)$} };
```

as in:

```
$ perl -le 'print $rx = do { local $" = "\t|\n\t"; qr{ ^ (?xis: @ARGV ) $ }mx }' good stuff goes here
(?^mx: ^ (?xis: good    |
        stuff   |
        goes    |
        here ) $ )
```

Nifty, eh?

Comment: Perl is so much more fun than other languages.

Comment: Had fun? Actually, you bring up a very good point: Perl is very efficient at compilation. I've always suspect that the idea that one way is more efficient than the other is bogus. My guess is that this expert didn't really know Perl. I notice his variable names are all over the place. Some are all caps, some have dashes, some strange camel casing, etc. I have a feeling he used "join" because he needed a way to concat a string and the standard stuff like commas didn't work. A quick looksee through the list of Perl functions brought him join.

Answer (score 1):

Interpolation is a little slower than joining a list. That said I've never known anyone to take it to this extreme.

You could use the `Benchmark` module to determine how much difference there is.

Also, you could ask this question over on http://perlmonks.org/. There are real gurus there who can probably give you the inner secrets much better than I can.

Comment: Performance is immaterial here.  It’s maintainability that matters.

Comment: @tchrist - I definitely agree. He just asked why someone might think it's better to do it that way. I think it probably has to do with taking performance to an extreme :)

Comment: interestingly on perl monks this appears to show that concatenation is the faster than join https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=654489

Answer (score 0):

All of those approaches are fine.

Join can sometimes be more powerful than `.` concatentate, particularly when some of the things you are joining are arrays:

```
join "/", "~", @document_path_elements, $myDocument;
```

Comment: This is the most important difference between join and `.` : join will take the arguments in array-context. I doubt that if all the arguments are strings, join is faster than `.` though.

Comment: @Konerak: Perl doesn’t have an “array context”, despite its `wantarray()` function. It has *list context*.

Comment: Thanks - sucks to learn about perl in French, you mess up on international sites. MySQL is worse though, took me 10 pages reading about `déclancheurs` before I realised they were talking about triggers (after seeing the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement ;))

Answer (score 0):

While recognizing that in all the examples I see here, there are no significant performance differences, a series of concatenation, whether with `.` or with double-quotish interpolation, is indeed going to be more memory-inefficient than a join, which precomputes the needed string buffer for the result instead of expanding it several times (potentially even needing to move the partial resutl to a new location each time).

I have a problem with the criticism I see leveled here; there are many right ways to speak perl, and this is certainly one of them.

Inconsistent indentation, on the other hand...